# Does my app make a call to HTTPS using UIApplication.shared.openURL?

Tags: ios, swift, https, app-store-connect

In App Store Connect, submitting my Export Compliance Information states this:

`If you are making use of ATS or making a call to HTTPS, you are required to submit a year-end self classification report to the US government.`

In my iOS app, I use the following line of code to redirect people from the app to a support page, which I assume would be on Safari:

`UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: https://` (my url) `)! as URL)`

Does this count as a call to HTTPS? I am not collecting user data. If so, what do I need to submit to the US government as I get no information from this - I just want people to be able to access my website from my game.

Comment: Does your URL use https? Then yes, it is https.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes it does, but do I have to do anything about it? I'm not collecting any data, so do I need to report anything to the US government? If yes, what do I need to report and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer, only just remembered this question existed so I'm posting it here.

In January 2020, I did have to submit a [year-end self classification report](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/product-guidance/high-performance-computers/223-new-encryption/1238-how-to-file-an-annual-self-classification-report). You have to email the .csv template they provide to [crypt-supp8@bis.doc.gov](http://crypt-supp8@bis.doc.gov) and
[enc@nsa.gov](http://enc@nsa.gov). Personally, my app was of type **5D992** for the ECCN, which is likely what many should be submitted under, especially if they are just a game. I would recommend reading their information thoroughly though, because your ECCN might be slightly different.

Answer (score -1):

I think you don’t need do any action. Because you just open url in safari, not call https in your app.